# Android populate Listview from resource XML

Tags: android, xml

Hi what i'm wanting to do is read an xml file and that has two values colour and name and displays the name and changes the background colour of that individual item in the list. Does anyone know how to do this?

heres my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <string-array name="menu_array">
    <item>
        <name>Page1</name>
        <colour>#ffffff</colour>
    </item> 
    <item>
        <name>Page2</name>
        <colour>#ffffBB</colour>
    </item> 
     <item>
        <name>Page3</name>
        <colour>#fff45f</colour>
    </item> 
    <item>
        <name>Page4</name>
        <colour>#ffff00</colour>
    </item> 
 </string-array> 
</resources>
```

Comment: Go for Multidimensional Array

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188137/android-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-arrays-xml/5188601#5188601

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to parse `item` values in your custom adapter or use two different arrays, one for names and another for colors

Answer (score 0):

Change your String Array to atleast look like this:

```
    <string-array name="menu_array">

    <item>
      Page1 #ffffff
    </item> 

    <item>
      Page2 #ffffBB
    </item> 

    <item>
     Page3 #fff45f
    </item> 

    <item>
     Page4 #ffff00
    </item> 

    </string-array>
```

I have tried to parse the string-array you specified,I obtained the result of the form:

```
   Page1 #ffffff
```

This is,as far as I am concerned practically useless as you will have to still split your code using(where list is the actual string array):

```
        String[] cmenu =list[i].split("#");
        item.name=cmenu[0];
        item.colour="#"+cmenu[1];
        menuList.add(item);
```

Or you could use a subString method to do it.However I could not parse the colour value from your arrangement(always gave me a NumberFormatException) while the one I specifed seemed to work fine with:

```
           int Color.parseColor(String color)
```

This is the code of the getView method of the custom adapter I created for the purpose of solving the problem:

```
            @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View row=convertView;
       TextView textView;
       if(row==null)
      {
        row=inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
        textView=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        row.setTag(R.id.text1,textView);
      }
       else
        textView=(TextView)row.getTag(R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(menuList.get(position).name);        
    try{    
        Log.d(TAG, menuList.get(position).colour);                  
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(menuList.get(position).colour));    
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
         Log.e(TAG, "Still does not work");
       }
    return row;
}
```

NOTE:item is an object of ColouredMenuItem which just wraps `String name,colour` in a class.

The customAdapter has the constructor:

```
     MadAdapter(Context context,List<ColouredMenuItem> list,int resourceId)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.menuList=list;
    this.resourceId=resourceId;
    inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

EDIT:You could also create an XML file that you could add to assets and parse it using any of the parsers available.